# How to interpret the results from a binary model done in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, binary-data, interpretation

This is a binary model that my colleagues and I developed that regards a connection between the distance (dependent variable) and overall satisfaction with public transport (covariate). I don't know how to interpret the results shown below.

[image: R glm output as an image]

Comment: Hello. So, we are trying to research how different aspects of the public transport system impact the overall satisfaction with the former. In this particular case (that you can see in the screenshot), we did a logit model, where we tried to see the correlation between distance of homes of the people surveyed and overall satisfaction with the PTS. We are not sure how to interpret the results, meaning the coefficients and residuals. Hopefully, this makes it a bit more clear. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the cite Katarina. I find your question unclear because (1) you claim to do a binary model - does that mean your dependent variable is binary? If so how is that consistent with the dependent variable being distance? It appears from the output - although I am guessing since output is incomplete - that you are running a glm model with binomial as link, in which case the dependent should be binary. I suppose distance is continuous and hence again I am confused. Please edit the question. You can include R output simply by using code tags.

Comment: Hello Jesper. Thank you for your reply! We have translated all variables to be binary, since we are working with qualitative data. Perhaps there are mistakes, since as I said, we are very confused, and maybe it cannot even be done with distance as a dependent variable. Yes, we did try to run a glm model with binomial as a link. I have other codes, but I do not know how to put it here as another screenshot. Perhaps you can give me your e-mail, and we can communicate directly? Once again, thank you for your response and help!

Comment: "We have translated all variables to be binary, since we are working with qualitative data". I find it hard to believe that "distance" is qualitative, what scale is the variable measured on? Are you sure you transformed this to be binary?

Comment: We divided it into levels (since distance was in classes of km) and then transformed it into binary. There were no errors and the results that we got are in the screenshot. Do you believe that to be a mistake?

Comment: Hello Katarina - ideally you would provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when posting a model like this. It's also a little unclear exactly what you want someone to answer here, would they go through every part of the output and explain that? It seems like it would be a lot of work, perhaps there's something more specific you're thinking of which hasn't come across with the way the post is written.

Comment: I strikes me as a very strange approach. You have data with an ordinal variable "overall satisfaction" and "distance" which it is probably safe to treat as a quantitative variable (depending on the nature of the sample you may have a lot of people with 0 distance, which may require special attention). My first choice of model for analyzing the relation between two such variables is certainly not a binary logit model. I would reconsider the model choice. This is as close as I get to saying what you are doing is a mistake, without actually saying it.

Comment: Hello. Basically what I am asking is if somebody can help me and interpret the results AKA the coefficients? I hope it is clear now. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Perhpas it is. As I said, we are very confused and lost at this point. :D Perhaps you can help me with another model? I will share the link here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384878/how-to-interpret-results-of-a-binary-model-in-r?noredirect=1#comment722630_384878

Comment: Perhaps you could update your post with something along the lines of *how should I interpret the coefficient in the output of this Logistic Regression* to make it clearer for others (information in the comments can be easily missed). Also try to keep in mind that people try to ensure posts on stackexchange have a fairly long life to them, and are able to help other users in future (which is why MWE's are encouraged). It might be helpful to copy paste the text from your model into your post as well ( format it as code so that the formatting doesn't get messed up).

Comment: Is the independent variable also binary?

Comment: Hi Jasper. Yes, everything in this case is binary. Could you try and interpret the coefficients that were given? Just to see if anything has been done right. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The question lacks a clear description of the problem. It seems that **distance** is the dependent variable and it is transformed into binary. Logistic regression with **satisfaction** (a categorical variable) as the independent variable is run here.

Anyway, the way to interpret the results obtained from a logistic regression model by `R` is well described in [this *ucla* page](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/). Interpretations are available for both categorical and continuous covariates.

Comment: If I read the output correctly, distance is not in the model. The relevant model is `glm(satisfaction~air)`

Comment: You are right @JesperHybel. Distance is not in the model but KM is in the model. I think KM (kilometer) is for distance. If you see the source codes in the picture's top left, there is the code for the model as: `logistic <- glm(KM ~ Satisfaction, data = survey, family = "binomial")`. However, I also think that there may be some mistakes in the analysis. But according to the problem, I've provided the way of interpreting logistic regression results by `R`. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Very useful reference. But, if you find one of your answers fits another question, it's a sign that the questions are duplicates; you can flag them as such (no need to repeat your answer).

Comment: Dear @Scortchi, I didn't know it. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Yes Jesper, you are right. The relevant model is glm( Satisfaction ~ Air)!