# How should I interpret the coefficient in the output of this Logistic Regression?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, binary-data

This is a binary model that my colleagues and I developed that regards a connection between the satisfaction with air (dependent variable) and overall satisfaction with public transport (covariate). I don't know how to interpret the results shown below. [image]